# How to combine 100 workbooks into a master workbook using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

This is the attempt to do so:

```
Sub GetSheets()

Dim Path As Variant
Dim filename As Variant
Dim sheet As Variant

Path = "C:\Users\Asus\Google Drive\Income Generating\Stock Market\Daily Quotes\PSEGet"
filename = Dir(Path & "\*.csv")
  Do While filename <> ""
  Workbooks.Open filename:=Path & filename, ReadOnly:=True
     For Each sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
     sheet.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
  Next sheet
     Workbooks(filename).Close
     filename = Dir()
  Loop
End Sub
```

When I press the Run Macro button, the file path is recognized, but the copying of the rows of data is not working. This error appears:

[image: Error]
[image: Error]

These are the files that I want to combine into a master worksheet. Located in  one folder:
[image: Directory]

The files I want to combine are shown here:
[Sample of CSV file](https://ufile.io/3jvrh)

Comment: For starters, you probably need a backslash between Path and "*.xls". In any event, that image shows a folder full of .csv's, not .xls'.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to change the code to .csv. But it is still not working. I'll try the backslashes

Comment: First, try to get a folder list of files to work with the loop. Once you have that right, work on collating the csvc into a single workbook.

Comment: ... and btw, *'it is still not working'* is not an error code nor a valid error description.

Comment: Breakpoint your code and find out what _is_ working.

Comment: Thank you for that. The backslash worked, and I updated the main post. I'm trying to figure out why the copy is failing

Comment: Can you explain why you are doing this? If you are trying to do data anlysis on a whole lot of data, loading CSV into a bunch of sheets is not going to make it any easier

Comment: Those are stock quotes from the stock market. The software I use provides data only a daily basis and there is no compiled version. In order to analyze them over a period of time, I need to combine them in one worksheet. They all have the same format so loading them into one worksheet is not a problem at all. It's like a database

Comment: Why not keep the individual files and use a master sheet to link to : effectively colkect the values that you need from each sheet : indirect() may be helpful.

Comment: Given the small size of the individual csvs, are those each individual stock symbols? Why aren't you consolidating multiple csvs to a single worksheet?

Comment: This can be a lot faster (and simpler) using DOS as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47546492/4914662) (possible duplicate)

Comment: I am keeping the individual files and at the same time have a master sheet i'm figuring out how to transfer to the master sheet. I'll link in a sample of one of the many csv files to give an idea.

Comment: I'll check the post @paulbica

Comment: I think I have an idea how to do what I need. I'll post an update soon

Comment: I posted the working solution. Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 0):

I came out with a working solution:

```
Option Explicit
Sub GetSheets()

Dim Path As Variant
Dim filename As Variant
Dim sheet As Variant
Dim Total_rows_active As Long
Dim Total_rows_compiled As Long

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Path = "C:\Users\Asus\Google Drive\Income Generating\Stock Market\Daily Quotes\PSEGet\"
filename = Dir(Path & "\*.csv")
    Do While filename <> ""
    Total_rows_compiled = Workbooks("Compiled Stock Quotes.xlsx").Worksheets("Compiled").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Workbooks.Open filename:=Path & filename, ReadOnly:=True
    Total_rows_active = Workbooks(filename).Sheets(1).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Workbooks(filename).Sheets(1).Range("A1:G" & Total_rows_active).Copy
    Workbooks("Compiled Stock Quotes.xlsx").Worksheets("Compiled").Range("A" & Total_rows_compiled + 1, "G" & Total_rows_compiled + Total_rows_active).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    Workbooks(filename).Close
    filename = Dir()
  Loop
```

The output of the code is here: [Compiled File](https://ufile.io/6jtgh)